How to improve performance of the following query to get nearby ship location
I have a Postgres table named shipData(total rows 700 millions). Which has ship location with reporting time and location in geometry format(combination of lat & lon). I have a shipID, I want to retrieve the nearby ship's location with in 1 nautical mile. I have 3 index on shipID, shipLocation, reportingTime column. I think the main time time is required for PostGIS ST_DWithin calculation.
I tried with the following query. At first I retrieve the selected ship position with my shipID and time range. Then I tried to get the nearby ship's location withe the help of PostGIS ST_DWithin method.
WITH selected_ship_positions AS (
    SELECT shipID, shipLocation, reportingTime
    FROM shipData
    WHERE shipID = 123456789 AND reportingTime BETWEEN '07/12/2024 02:00 UTC' AND '07/12/2024 02:10 UTC'
)
SELECT sd.shipID, sd.shipname, sd.shipLocation, sd.reportingTime
FROM shipData sd
JOIN selected_ship_positions ssp
    ON sd.reportingTime BETWEEN ssp.reportingTime - INTERVAL '1 minutes' AND ssp.reportingTime + INTERVAL '1 minutes'
    AND ST_DWithin(sd.shipLocation::geography, ssp.shipLocation::geography, 1852) -- 1 nautical miles
WHERE sd.shipID != ssp.shipID 


The query gives result in 2 min. I want to get the response with in 15-20sec. How to improve the performance?

Please check this thread which explains the underlying issue and how to improve it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56004598/1253336

When asking questions about performance, include the table DDL (including constraints and indexes) and the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS,VERBOSE). Since performance issues usually only manifest with large volumes of data, it might not be practical to create a reproducible example; however, having the DDL and explain plan details often is sufficient to expose potential areas for improvement.

Please disclose information as instructed for postgresql-performance questions.

@TimothyDalton Thanks for the linked question. As per the suggestion on your linked question, the performance is improved after adding an index with the following query:
CREATE INDEX ON shipData USING gist((shipLocation::geography));

I tried citus in my projects where response time matters so I suggest using Citus with PostgreSQL can significantly improve the performance of your query by distributing the data and computation across multiple nodes.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
